# C# For each loop in a a table?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, foreach

I'm trying to display various information with the help of a for each loop.
I've created a for each loop, that iterates through a list of item. In this list there is another list of items.

As for now it's displayed like this: 
[image]

My code is:

```
@foreach (Invoice invoice in ViewBag.Invoices)
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Customer</th>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Total Price</th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (OrderItem orderItem in invoice.OrderItems)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>@invoice.Customer.Firstname @invoice.Customer.Lastname</td>
            <td>@orderItem.Product.Title </td>
            <td>@orderItem.Quantity </td>
            <td>@orderItem.Product.Price </td>            
            <td>@orderItem.TotalPrice</td>
        </tr>
        }

        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="border-top">@invoice.TotalPrice</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```

However, I don't want it to display the customers name twice. And I don't want to have the customer on its own row. Therefore I tried to put the starting tag along with the customer outside of the foreach loop, and instead ending the foreach loop with a `<tr>` tag. So it'd look like this:

```
@foreach (Invoice invoice in ViewBag.Invoices)
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Customer</th>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Total Price</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td>@invoice.Customer.Firstname @invoice.Customer.Lastname</td>

        @foreach (OrderItem orderItem in invoice.OrderItems)
        {
            <td>@orderItem.Product.Title </td>
            <td>@orderItem.Quantity </td>
            <td>@orderItem.Product.Price </td>            
            <td>@orderItem.TotalPrice</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        }


            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="border-top">@invoice.TotalPrice</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```

**UPDATED SOLUTION**

I followed the wise words of @Ed Plunkett and initialized a local string to null. The I created an if/else statement to check if the previous customer has been set, and initialized the value of the previous customer in the end of the loop.

```
@{string prevCust = null; }

@foreach (Invoice invoice in ViewBag.Invoices)
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Customer</th>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Total Price</th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (OrderItem orderItem in invoice.OrderItems)
        {
            <tr>
            @if (prevCust != invoice.Customer.Firstname + invoice.Customer.Lastname)
            {
                <td>@invoice.Customer.Firstname @invoice.Customer.Lastname</td>
            }
            else
            {
                <td></td>
            }

            <td>@orderItem.Product.Title </td>
            <td>@orderItem.Quantity </td>
            <td>@orderItem.Product.Price </td>
            <td>@orderItem.TotalPrice</td>
        </tr>

            prevCust = invoice.Customer.Firstname + invoice.Customer.Lastname;
        }

        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="border-top">@invoice.TotalPrice</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```

Comment: Take up that "}" character, before </tr>?

Comment: You're opening the row (`<tr>`) once and closing the row (`</tr>`) *zero or more* times. Whether or not Razor is smart enough to know you're doing that, don't do that, because your HTML will be broken. Just make a local variable String `prevCustomerName`, initialize to null, and update it at the *end* of the loop block. At the beginning of the loop block, if the new customer name is the same as `prevCustomerName`, don't insert it into the HTML for that row.

Comment: btw, You forgot one </tr> after your third <tr>

Comment: What should happen when your collection doesn´t contain any elements? In this case the output was `<tr><tr>` which is invalid.

Comment: Sorry, I put an <tr> too much in the code, I edited it now as how I meant it to be.

Comment: @StephanOlsen OK, that's actually pretty neat thinking, except you still need an empty customer name cell for the non-first rows. Nevertheless, it looks like Razor isn't clever enough to figure out that what you're doing makes sense. You might try replacing the inner loop `</tr>\n<tr>` with `Response.Write("</tr><tr>")` (not sure if that's the right method these days) to hide it from Razor. Ugly, I know.

Comment: Thanks @Ed Plunkett, I did as you described in your previous comment and it worked. Thanks! :)

Comment: Hey @StephanOlsen - Can your `Invoices` model have more than one different customer or is it one customer per invoice?

Comment: It's only one customer per invoice @garfbradaz

Comment: Thanks @StephanOlsen. Then you could create a **ViewModel** which encapsulates the Customer details as single properties. Then have a list with your `OrderDetails`

You View itself will then need to point to the ViewModel, and just iterate through the OrderDetails for the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it caveman style: Just make a local variable `String prevCustomerName`, initialize to null, and update it at the end of the loop block. At the beginning of the loop block, if the new customer name is the same as `prevCustomerName`, don't insert it into the HTML for that row.

I enjoyed your original code with `</tr>\n<tr>` in the inner loop, but it took me a minute to figure out what you were doing, and Razor seems to be totally baffled. And you still need to ugly it up with a special case to add an empty cell on non-first rows. If you're stuck putting in an `if` either way, do the caveman.

Answer (score 0):

When resorting to iteration in a table, it's helpful (even for yourself, not just for razor or whatever view engine you are using) to keep it as structured and simple as possible.

(the comments on your question should be enough explanation as to why this is a good idea)

try using multiple tr's per invoice to achieve your goals. for example :

```
@foreach (Invoice invoice in ViewBag.Invoices)
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Customer</th>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Total Price</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td colspan="4">@invoice.Customer.Firstname @invoice.Customer.Lastname</td>
        </tr>

        @foreach (OrderItem orderItem in invoice.OrderItems)
        {
            <tr>
              <td>@orderItem.Product.Title </td>
              <td>@orderItem.Quantity      </td>
              <td>@orderItem.Product.Price </td>            
              <td>@orderItem.TotalPrice    </td>
            </tr>
        }

        <tr>
            <td colspan="4"></td>
            <td class="border-top">@invoice.TotalPrice</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```

You could even resort to generating one table per invoice if that helps make things simpler for you.

Comment: This definitely works, but I don't want the customer to be displayed on its own row. I want it to be displayed on the same row as the products. With your code (I added an extra empty <td></td> to push the informations one column) it will result in this: http://puu.sh/ryz8M/3bebb239f5.png

I added a border for clarity in this example.

Answer (score 0):

Without being ASP-expert I suppose you have to handle the first row differently then the others :

```
<tr>
  <td>@invoice.Customer.Firstname @invoice.Customer.Lastname</td>
  <td>@orderItem.Product.Title </td>
  <td>@orderItem.Quantity      </td>
  <td>@orderItem.Product.Price </td>            
  <td>@orderItem.TotalPrice    </td>
</tr>
```

Now handle the rest in the loop omitting the first (already handled) element:

```
@foreach (OrderItem orderItem in invoice.OrderItems.Skip(1))
{
    <tr>
      <td/>
      <td>@orderItem.Product.Title </td>
      <td>@orderItem.Quantity      </td>
      <td>@orderItem.Product.Price </td>            
      <td>@orderItem.TotalPrice    </td>
    </tr>
}
```

A more generic approach would be using a `for`-loop with an index and check if you´re handling the first element:

```
@for(int i = 0; invoice.OrderItems.Count; i++)
{
    <tr>
      <td>@(i != 0 ? invoice.Customer.Firstname + " " + invoice.Customer.Lastname : "")</td>
      <td>@invoice.OrderItems[i].Product.Title </td>
      <td>@invoice.OrderItems[i].Quantity      </td>
      <td>@invoice.OrderItems[i].Product.Price </td>            
      <td>@invoice.OrderItems[i].TotalPrice    </td>
    </tr>
}
```

However I´m not sure if this is even valid ASP-syntax.

Comment: it'll work, but that's not DRY. you're doing the same thing twice, and in your other example you are doing an unnecesary check on every iteration.

Comment: Your ternary operator isn't valid razor code in the second example.

Comment: i think you were going for
`@(i != 0 ? invoice.Customer.Firstname + " " + invoice.Customer.Lastname : "")`

Comment: @TimothyGroote Thanks for your support, I´m more familiar with JSP.

Comment: quite a world of difference eh? :)

Comment: @TimothyGroote As Java against C#, similar on *what you do*, but very different on the actual syntax.